# PHP Strange character before £ sign?

Tags: php, character-encoding, mojibake

For some reason i get a `Â`£76756687 weird character when i type a £ into a text field on my form?

Comment: does the form show it, or does it end up somewhere else? I'm guessing UTF-8/ISO-8859-1 missmatch

Comment: Is it a plain text or HTML email?

Comment: You'll still need to set the encoding then - as long as the character set is the same on the email and form page all should be well. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suspect, it's a character encoding issue - is the page set to use a charset of UTF-8? (You can't go wrong with this encoding really.) Also, you'll probably want to entity encode the pound symbol on the way out (`&pound;`)

As an example character set (for both the form page and HTML email) you could use:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

That said, is there a good reason for the user to have to enter the currency symbol? Would it be a better idea to have it as either a static text item or a drop down to the left of the text field? (Feel free to ignore if I'm talking arse and you're using a freeform textarea or summat.)

Comment: doesnt seem to make a difference :|

Comment: The information inside the document is ignored if the information is already stated on a higher level like HTTP.

Comment: Are you storing the data in a database (or any intermediate area) prior to creating the email? (If so, have you checked the connection and table character sets?)

Answer (score 5):

You’re probably using UTF-8 as character encoding but don’t declare your output correctly. Because the `£` character (U+00A3) is encoded in UTF-8 with 0xC2A3. And that byte sequence represents the two characters `Â` and `£` when interpreted with ISO 8859-1.

So you just need to specify your character encoding correctly. In PHP you can use the [`header` function](http://php.net/header) to set the proper value for [*Content-Type* header field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) like:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

But make sure that you call this function before any output. Otherwise the HTTP header is already sent and you cannot modify it.